# How to improve update performance of an SSIS 2008 package that runs fine on 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm migrating my data warehouse from *`SQL Server 2005`* to **`SQL Server 2008`** . There is a large performance decrease on the table updates. The inserts work great.

I'm using the same SSIS package in both environments, but 2008 still doesn't update right.

I've run update stats full on all tables. The process uses a temp table. I've dropped all indexes (except one needed for the update) but none of these measures helped. I also wrote an update statement that mimics what SSIS is doing, and it runs fast as expected.

The update process uses a data flow task (there are other things in the task, like inserting into a `processed` table to know what data was used in the update).

This is a brand new database with nothing else running on it. Any suggestions?

Captured statistics IO

- 2005, CPU=0, Reads=150
- 2008, CPU=1700, Reads=33,000

Database RAM:

- 2005, 40GB Total / 18 Sql Server
- 2008, 128GB Total / 110GB Sql Server

Comment: Thanks for the link @Siva. I'm already using a staging table and I don't want to rewrite this process since the problem seems to span more than just this table. Is there something else in that solution that I missed that could help? +1 on your answer, it's very thorough.

Comment: Capture and compare your Actual Execution Plans. Perhaps they are different between the SSMS version and the package version?

Comment: @billinkc - there are definite differences. On 2005, CPU=0, Reads=150; 2008, CPU=1700, Reads=33,000. So there is definitely something there. Any suggestions while I look for it?

Comment: How does your hardware compare between 2005 and 2008? I saw this question over on dba.se where more [RAM lead to poor performance](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33490/increased-ram-worse-performance). We might flag this ticket and get it punted over to dba.se and see if this isn't a database thing and not an SSIS thing.

Comment: There is a difference in the RAM on the servers. I'll reduce how much RAM SQL Server gets and see if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was found in the execution plan. The plan in 2008 was using different tables build the update statement. Background: since we use indexed views which don't allow any other access while querying those tables, we built smaller/leaner tables the iViews use rather than our dimensions to keep them available to users. The optimizer was choosing those tables rather than the ones we specified in the query.

When I originally did the explain plans, I used the wrong query, which did not have this functionality. This made all the difference.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for coming back and explaining!  You should accept this as your answer, however.

Comment: I will, but I have to wait for 2 days.